# Java program to simulate user saving a page in Firefox

Tags: java, browser

I want to emulate a user saving a webpage into a directory (after login) from an external program in Java.

I found that this kind of things are usually done in testing suites such as Selenium or iMacros. Still, how could this be done in normal Java program?

Could I do it using DJnativeSwing?

Comment: What do you mean by "a normal Java Program". I've written several "normal java programs" that use Selenium...

Comment: i mean without using selenium or imacros..can this be done only using java and firefox? can we send a "save" command to firefox from java program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform the action with java.awt.Robot, which will really invoke Firefox. Or do you like to make a http-request with java? Did you think about images, videos, flash, javascript, cookies, referrer?

Comment: after firing up firefox,i need to ask the user to login and then download a few pages of that site with different url(all this i have to because the site doesnt have restapi and there is no way of authorization for desktop applications other than oauth(which requires u to have server)).i think i can use robot class to control the input and save pages..thanks for the answer..i will get back to you after trying:)